# Laravel: Get model attributes by key array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, model, attributes

I'm attempting to access a models attributes by an array of keys. The desired functionality would work something like `$model->getAttribute('name')`, but accept an array instead of a string.

Let's say we had a model with attributes name of 'A', age of 2 and blood_type of 'B'.

```
$attributesToPull = ['name', 'age'];
$model->getAttributes($attributesToPull);

// returns ['A', 2]
```

I've checked through the Laravel docs and cant find anything that quite fits.

The results dont need to come straight from the model, they can be pulled into their own associative array using `$model->getAttributes()` and then have a native PHP array function such as `array_intersect` to filter the results, but even then I can't seem to find a function that will allow me to filter an associative array with an indexed array.

Does anyone know how I could go about this, ideally without using a loop or a callback? The answer can be pretty open, it can return a collection or an array and use either the associative array of the model attributes or call a function on the model itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Model has a `only` method:

```
$model->only($attributesToPull);
```

Comment: oh my god I knew there was something! haha. I've used that function before and totally forgot about it, I've been searching the docs for keys or attributes. I hope no future employers see this!